# science fiction short story of a house of misfits with talking toaster?

Tags: story-identification, psychic

I'm pretty sure I read it in an anthology or in Analog magazine.  The characters include a man who fixes holes in the universe, a talking toaster, and a few other 'misfits', and a woman who sort of keeps track of them all.  There's a visit by a guy who I think has some mental powers of persuasion, and he ends up breaking the toaster (I think).

The main character is a young man with a psychic ability to control people, and he stumbles across the house of 'misfits' which include a child firestarter, an old man (Mr. Santiago?) who somehow is responsible for holding the universe together, and a shapeshifter named Toby who takes the form of whoever the person nearest to it loves the most. He stays there for a while and helps them out, but the woman who runs the place is disturbed when he uses his psychic abilities to convince a cashier he's paid for groceries.

Comment: The TV show *Red Dwarf* comes close in some episodes...

Comment: Yes, I think they got the toaster idea from the short story.

Comment: That sounds like the kind of thing Rudy Rucker might have written, but I've not read that particular story.

Comment: Michael Marshall Smith's *One Of Us* also features talking appliances, but I don't remember the other plot elements.

Comment: Thanks @AvnerShahar-Kashtan! It's not that one, but "One of Us" looks interesting and I'll pick up the e-version.

Comment: The Brave Little Toaster?

Comment: Do these details sound familiar - Main character is a young man with a psychic ability to control people, he stumbles across the house of 'misfits' which include a child firestarter, an old man (Mr. Santiago?) who somehow is responsible for holding the universe together, and a shapeshifter named Toby who takes the form of whoever the person nearest to it loves the most? He stays there for a while and helps them out, but the woman who runs the place is disturbed when he uses his psychic abilities to convince a cashier he's paid for groceries, and when he keeps sneaking up to the attic to see To

Comment: Yes,that's it! And the conflict is over Toby,who he influences too much for the attacker's taste. And there is a confrontation between them which the toaster is somehow involved in, and the toaster ends up broken. Do you remember the title? I know I read it in an anthology or Analog. Can't remember which.

Comment: That should have read *caretaker*, not attacker - touchscreen autocorrect.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/222559/short-story-about-a-young-psychic-man-who-disrupts-a-home-full-of-unusual-people (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 10):

*[A Place to Stay for a Little While](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42554)* by Jim Aikin

[Excerpt](https://books.google.com/books?id=ud0SdiN5NSoC&q=%22was%20a%20very%20unusual%20household%20among%20whose%20members%20%22&dq=%22was%20a%20very%20unusual%20household%20among%20whose%20members%20%22&hl=bg&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjehor5_83lAhVUh1wKHZylBk0Q6AEIJzAA):

> *It was a very unusual household among whose members were a man who patched holes in the world, a shapechanger, and even a talking radio.
> It was also a very peaceful domicile until a man who had the ability
> to control minds became a resident.*
>
> “I can't cope,” Cynthia Lutz said to the radio. “I simply cannot
> cope.” “Oh, come on,” the radio said. It was a wooden table model that
> dated from about 1933. "Things aren't that bad. Things have been this
> bad before.”

Comment: Nice!  How did you find it?

Comment: @DavidW, I searched for _"Toby " attic "science fiction"_ with 20th century range in Google Books and snippet from the story in "Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine" appeared. After that I googled phrases from there.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been searching for this off and on since I posted here over 5 years ago - still have that issue of Asimov's in the attic.