# Anthology: Vampirism as a cure for HIV; house full of odd characters; arrows on a path through the afterlife

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

In the mid-90's, I read a wonderful collection of stories that I've been trying to find since.  The book was titled something like *Year's Best Science Fiction & Fantasy Stories*, I believe published in some time in the 1980's or early 1990's.

Some of the stories I remember included:

- A women tries to convince a vampire to transform her as a way to cure her HIV infection.
- A man with the power to control minds comes upon a house populated by other strange characters, including a sentient radio, an old man with a lightning bolt tattoo who flies around the world to keep the Earth's plates stitched together, and a woman in the attic who uncontrollably shape-shifts into the love of whoever she talks to.
- A story in the afterlife, where people are endlessly walking down a path, and two characters begin unlocking the subtle code of the arrows inscribed on the ground.

Any help tracking this book down would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "The Year's Best Science Fiction" is an extremely popular annual anthology, published since 1984. [Wikipedia has contents for all the annuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Year%27s_Best_Science_Fiction) - I would recommend looking at contents of each until you recognize one or more stories

Comment: Or recognize the cover.

Comment: I think somebody was looking for your #2 story in another old (and unanswered) question at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49925/science-fiction-short-story-of-a-house-of-misfits-with-talking-toaster -- the extra details might jog your memory and give you a chance to solve the mystery.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*[The Year's Best Fantasy Stories 13](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?50735)* (1987).

The first story you described is *Something in the Blood* by Richard Purtill.

The second one is *[A Place to Stay for a Little While](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42554)* by Jim Aikin.

[Excerpt](https://books.google.com/books?id=ud0SdiN5NSoC&q=%22was%20a%20very%20unusual%20household%20among%20whose%20members%20%22&dq=%22was%20a%20very%20unusual%20household%20among%20whose%20members%20%22&hl=bg&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjehor5_83lAhVUh1wKHZylBk0Q6AEIJzAA):

> *It was a very unusual household among whose members were a man who patched holes in the world, a shapechanger, and even a talking radio.
> It was also a very peaceful domicile until a man who had the ability
> to control minds became a resident.*
>
> “I can't cope,” Cynthia Lutz said to the radio. “I simply cannot
> cope.” “Oh, come on,” the radio said. It was a wooden table model that
> dated from about 1933. "Things aren't that bad. Things have been this
> bad before.”

The third story could be *Long, Long Ago* by R. Chetwynd-Hayes.